# ElasticSearch+Pyspark Reading Slow Performance

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I wanted to get some query results from Elasticsearch using Pyspark but my reading performance is so slow. I am using 1 worker and 1 master node in my spark-class here is my created SparkSession code

'''

```
spark = SparkSession\
        builder\
        appName\
        config("spark.executor.memory","1g")\
        config("spark.executor.cores","4")\
        config("spark.driver.cores","1")\
        config("spark.driver.memory","1g")\
        config("spark.cores.max","15")\
        config("spark.es.mapping.date.rich","false")\
```

'''

and my reading DataFrame code is

'''

```
df =  spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
      .option("es.nodes", "IP")
      .option("es.nodes.wan.only","true")
      .option("es.port","port")
      .option("es.scroll.size","10000")
      .option("es.scroll.keepalive","10m")
      .option("es.batch.size.entries","2000")
      .option("numPartitions","100")
      .load("myindex")
```

'''

when i submit dataframe with this numPartitions option, my dataframe partition number is still is "1" when i run df.rdd.getNumPartitions() but then i can rerun with repartition(100). But i still can't understand why my numPartitions option is not working in the first place.

Thus when i do some filtering and selecting then run collect(), my job takes a lots of time in Stage 0.

when i look at localhost:4040, i can clearly see that my job has two stages, Stage 0 only runs in one executor and takes a lot of time but stage 2 can do parallel jobs. Why my Stage 0 takes so long, and i can't do any parallel tasking in that issue?

Thanks for your advices.